# ng-dropdown-panel in ng-select - how to keep its custom styles even when appendTo="body" is used

Tags: angular, scss-mixins, angular-ngselect

For demonstartions created a Stackblitz with almost an empty project with `ng-select` with no extra custom styles. And getting this issue of width of the `ng-dropdown-panel` when I am passing `appendTo="body"`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-byjnda

Details below

I am using `ng-select` and have quite a bit of custom styles defined to it as below in a .scss file using `@mixin` as below

```css
@mixin custom-ng-select {
  @include custom-ng-select-ip();
  @include custom-text-body-light-2();

  caret-color: mat-color($sdk-secondary, 500);

  &.ng-select .ng-select-container {
    box-shadow: none;
    min-height: $custom-ng-select-height;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &.ng-select.ng-select-single .ng-select-container {
    height: $custom-ng-select-height;
  }

 &.ng-select
    &.ng-dropdown-panel
    .ng-dropdown-panel-items
    .ng-option.ng-option-marked {
    padding-left: $custom-ng-select-pl;
    height: $custom-ng-select-height;
  }

...and many more styles...
```

And then in my Angular app's global `styles.scss` file getting this custom styles @mixin as below

```
.ng-select {
  @include custom-ng-select();
}
```

**And this is working fine as expected.**

But when I am rendering `<ng-select>` with `appendTo="body"` then the `ng-dropdown-panel` is no more taking the custom styles and the reason is as below per [ng-select official doc](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/3018a1098ba2ad06fbdf4dfe60209087cbd68185/src/demo/app/examples/append-to-example/append-to-example.component.html)

`By default dropdown panel is rendered as child element of ng-select, but you can append dropdown to any element using appendTo`

That is in below case `ng-dropdown-panel` is no more a child of `ng-select`

```
    <ng-select
      appendTo="body"
      [items]="items"
      [bindLabel]="'name'"      
    >
    </ng-select>
```

How do I do that, any guidance will be a life-saver.

Below screenshot is the top-most `ng-select` and this is how `ng-dropdown-panel`'s custom styles is getting broken when using with `appendTo="body"`

[image]

And below screenshots where I have NOT used `appendTo="body"`

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can put your custom styling on ng-dropdown-panel in stead of on ng-select?

Answer (score 3):

If you specify your class, you can access to the ng-dropdown-panel by your class.

```
<ng-select
  class="custom-class"
  appendTo="body"
  [items]="items"
  [bindLabel]="'name'"      
>
</ng-select>
```

Then you will have the custom class on ng-dropdown-panel in the html
([like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoVZb.png)), and you could access by scss:

```
ng-dropdown-panel.custom-class {
   min-width: 500px !important;
}
```

**Note:** I have ViewEncapsulation.None in the component for overriding ng-select styles:

```
@Component({
   selector: '...',
   templateUrl: './...],
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

If you want to apply styles since another place, like styles.scss, maybe you have to override styles with ::ng-deep or something like that.

I hope I've helped

**Update:** If you want apply dynamic classes, you can try this workarround from [yanotoma](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1756#issuecomment-706747595)